# Is it true that $\{x^4+y^2+z^2:\ x,y,z\in\mathbb Z[i]\}=\{a+2bi:\ a,b\in\mathbb Z\}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, sums-of-squares

Recall that the ring of Gaussian integers is
$$\mathbb Z[i]=\{a+bi:\ a,b\in\mathbb Z\}.$$
Clearly
$$(a+bi)^2=a^2-b^2+2abi\ \ \mbox{and}\ \ (a+bi)^4=(a^2-b^2)^2-4a^2b^2+4ab(a^2-b^2)i.$$

**Question.** Is it true that $\{x^4+y^2+z^2:\ x,y,z\in\mathbb Z[i]\}=\{a+2bi:\ a,b\in\mathbb Z\}$?

**Evidence.**  Via Mathematica I have found that
\begin{align} &\{x^4+y^2+z^2:\ x,y,z\in\{r+si:\ r,s\in\{-14,\ldots,14\}\}\}
\\&\quad \supseteq\{a+2bi:\ a,b\in\mathbb Z\ \mbox{and}\ |a+2bi|\le 50\}.
\end{align}
For example,
$$43+22i=2^4+(14-11i)^2+(11-13i)^2$$
and
$$-34+26i=(2+i)^4+(13-i)^2+(1+14i)^2=(4+i)^4+(11-11i)^2+(1+14i)^2.$$

**Motivation.** The question is motivated by my following result (cf. [my 2017 JNT paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2016.11.008))
$$\{x^4+y^2+z^2+w^2:\ x,y,z,w=0,1,2,\ldots\}=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$$
which refines Lagrange's four-square theorem.

I conjecture that the question has a positive answer, but I'm unable to prove this. Your comments are welcome!

Comment: FWIW - some more evidence (with a short c++ program) if you let r,s above be in {-60, 60}, the only a, b you miss in [-130, 130]^2 is (6, -73)

Comment: As you find a solution for $6+2\times73i$, there is a solution for $6-2\times73i$ (the conjugate of $6+2\times73i$) too.

Comment: yes, I discarded symmetries

Comment: Now I find a solution for $6-2\times73i$: $$6-146i=(2-i)^4+(61+6i)^2+(7-61i)^2.$$

Comment: As $(r-si)^4=(s+ri)^4$, we may restrict $x$ to the form $r+si$ with $r\ge0$ and $s\ge0$. To check the question efficiently, one may assume $x=r+si$ with $r,s$ relatively small.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it is true that $\{ x^{4} + y^{2} + z^{2} : x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}[i] \} = \{ a + 2bi : a, b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. Indeed, one can even take $x$ to be either $0$ or $1$ in all cases. Because $y^{2}+z^{2} = (y+iz)(y-iz)$ is reducible, this is analogous to the statement that every integer can be written in the form $x^{2}-y^{2}$ or $x^{2}-y^{2} + 1$ with $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Suppose that $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a$ is odd. Then
$$
  a + 2bi = 0^{4} + \left(\frac{a+1}{2} + bi\right)^{2} + \left(b - \left(\frac{a-1}{2}\right)i\right)^{2}.
$$
If $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a$ is even, then $a-1$ is odd, and the identity above allows one to write $a-1 + 2bi = y^{2} + z^{2}$ with $y, z \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$. Hence, $a + 2bi = x^{4} + y^{2} + z^{2}$ with $y, z \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $x = 1$.